# Плавная прокрутка к якорю

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код прокрутки к якорю:

```
function scroll_page(){

        var target = document.location.hash.replace("#","");
        var selector = 'div[id='+target+']';
        alert(selector);
        $('html,body').animate( {scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top -60}, 2000);
        return false;
    };
```

И вызывается он:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  scroll_page();
    });
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на ссылку резко прыгает к этому блоку, а потом плавно подъезжает к его верхушке.

Comment: Посмотрите направо, там есть столбец **Похожие**, и попробуйте, что-то из предложенных методов. P.S. Вам событие надо вешать не на изменение урла в адресной строке (тут наверняка браузер сам уже страницу прокрутил), а на клик ссылок с именами якорей.

Comment: нашел то, что хотел. но почему-то скролл останавливается не доезжая блока. это происходит с любом кодом.